# File.list() returns null on root directory "/"

Tags: android, java-io

new File("/").list() returns null on some Android phones, and a normal list of files on other phones. Why? If I cannot rely on it to work, what is an alternative?

Comment: The phone on which it does not work is Asus Zenfone 3 Max with Android 7.0

Comment: Yes this is normal behaviour under Android 7.0. You are not allowed to list /.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point me to a doc which says so?

Comment: I just tried it on a Samsung S8 running 7.0 and it's working.

Comment: Is your target version 7?

Comment: No, target sdk version 22 (Android 5.1)